# failed install NTP server because ibopts25 not available

Tags: server, software-installation, 15.04

i have ubuntu server 15.04 , and now i tried to install NTP server but i can't install because some packages was missing 
sudo apt-get install

```
root@server:/home/technical# apt-get install ntp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libopts25
Suggested packages:
  ntp-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libopts25 ntp
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 481 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,698 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libopts25 ntp
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main libopts25 amd64   1:5.18.4-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main ntp amd64 1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu6.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/autogen/libopts25_5.18.4-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ntp/ntp_4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu6.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

any body know how to fix this?

Comment: Vivid has been End of Life for a *very* long time, and is not supported anymore.  Use a supported release.  Or, see [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) for how to install software in or upgrade from the old release you are on.  Note that if you continue to use the EOL release, you won't be able to easily get support here on Ask Ubuntu for your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 15.04 is not supported since **2 years**. That is why there is no data available to it.

It is in fact not a LTS relese. Update to a supported release e.g. 16.04 (LTS) or 17.10.